# I can't change my text color through jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, api, dom, bootstrap-5

I have tried to apply a styling condition through an if statement in my JQuery based on an API result, but I can't seem to see the color change. I have assigned an ID to try change the color through css.

```js
$.getJSON(API2, function (result) {
  console.log(result);

  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var tabledata = `
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">`+ result[i].Season + `</th>
          <td><p class="td-item">`+ result[i].DateTime + `</p></td>
          <td><p class="td-item">`+ result[i].Name + `</td>
          <td><p class="td-item" class="stat">`+ result[i].Status + `</p></td>
        </tr>
    `;

    var stat = result[i].Status;
    $(".event").append(tabledata);
  }

  if (stat == "final") {
    $(".td-stat").attr('id', 'td-stat');
    console.log(stat);
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(".td-stat").attr('id', 'td-stat');` is this element supposed to be attached with the table in the code in your example? Is `stat` "final" always set in the last loop iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```
$.getJSON(API2, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  $("<tbody>").appendTo(".event");
  $.each(result, function(i, r) {
    var row = $("<tr>").appendTo($(".event tbody"));
    $("<th>", {
      scope: "row"
    }).html(r.Season).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html($("<p>", {
      class: "td-item"
    }).html(r.DateTime)).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html($("<p>", {
      class: "td-item"
    }).html(r.Name)).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html($("<p>", {
      class: "td-item stat " + (r.Status == "final" ? "final" : "")
    }).html(r.Status)).appendTo(row);
  });
});
```

This creates a `tbody` and populates rows for each entry in `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You should give them an Id or get them like an Array and try to loop over them like but for changing color you should use this :

```
$("#yourElementId").css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: I see that not all the code posted, I've done this, does it seem right?

```
} if (stat == "final") {
            $(".td-stat").attr('id', 'td-stat');
            console.log(stat);
        }
```